# Strange characters in the begining of the file after writing in Python

Tags: python, windows, file, fwrite

I want to do a lot of boring C# code replacements automatically through a python script. I read all lines of the file, transform them, truncate the whole file, write new strings and close it.

```
f = open(file, 'r+')
text = f.readlines()
# some changes
f.truncate(0)
for line in text:
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

All my changes are written. But some strange characters in the beginning of the file appear. I don't know how to avoid them. Even if I open with `encoding='utf-8-sig'` it doesn't help.

I tried truncate whole file besides the 1st line like this:

```
import sys
f.truncate(sys.getsizeof(text[0]))
for index in range(1, len(text), 1):
    f.write(text[index])
```

But in this case more than 1st line is writing instead of only first line.

**EDIT**
I tried this:

```
f.truncate(len(text[0]))
for index in range(1, len(text), 1):
    f.write(text[index])
```

And the first line has written correct but next one with the same issue. So I think this characters from the end of the file and I try to write after them.

Comment: Do they look like https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark ?

Comment: No, in Visual Studio they look like spaces but affect code correctness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f=open(file, 'r+')
text = f.readlines() # After reading all the lines, the pointer is at the end of the file.
# some changes
f.seek(0) # To bring the pointer back to the starting of the file.
f.truncate() # Don't pass any value in truncate() as it means number of bytes to be truncated by default size of file.
for line in text:
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Check out this [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_truncate.htm) for more details.

Comment: Oh yes, it works fine! Thank you!
Am I right that these symbols from end of file and I write right after them?

Comment: You are at the end of the file and when you call `f.truncate(0)` it means `truncate 0 byte from the file` which doesn't do anything there. Even I don't know why you see those characters.

Comment: FYI, on Windows, `open` defaults to ANSI, which depends on the system locale. If the file is UTF-8, the `utf-8-sig` encoding is the most compatible with Windows tools, since many expect a UTF-8 BOM. Note that in this case when you `seek(0)` it resets the file's internal state, so the next write will include the required BOM.

Comment: I actually don't know much about `encoding` just few names and definition, it would be a great help if you could share a link so that the answer can be optimized or it becomes better.

Comment: Python 3 [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) has an `encoding` parameter, which defaults to the encoding returned by [`locale.getpreferredencoding`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding). On Windows, this will be a [standard encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) for the system's ANSI codepage (e.g. "cp1252" for Western Europe and America).